# Get field values of newly created record other than Id

Tags: apex, database, database.insert, saveresult

Is it technical feasible to obtain fields like OwnerId, Name from newly inserted record from database.Saveresult?

Apex code:

```
for(Database.SaveResult sr: srList){
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        Id a;
        a = sr.OwnerId
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible from `Database.saveResult`. From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm), it seems to be used largely as "It worked!/It didn't work!".

```
// Create two accounts, one of which is missing a required field
Account[] accts = new List<Account>{
    new Account(Name='Account1'),
new Account()};
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(accts, false);

// Iterate through each returned result
for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted account. Account ID: ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

As this example demonstrates though and as you say in the question title, you can get the `Id` using the `getId()` method of the record and thus to get fields like `OwnerId`  by using this method.

You could simply add the `Id` to a `Set<Id>` and query based on that `Set<Id>` assuming things like the sObject type are persistent.

```
Set<Id> myAccountSet = new Set<Id>(); // Declare an empty Set

// Do other Database.SaveResult stuff...

if (sr.isSuccess()) { // The same conditional statement as in the for loop before
    myAccountSet.add(sr.getId()); // Add it to the Set created earlier
}

List<Account> myAccountList = [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :myAccountSet]; // Query it!
```